# Trying to Access a Control in Parent Listview from Nested Listview

Tags: listview, nested

Setup:
Listview with Nested Listview with Email Address Links

When i click the email link (choice), I need the ID of the record from the Parent Listview (Stored in a Label text)

OR

On the Parent Listview - find a Label control in the nested ListView and store the ID into it at that time so I may access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void LV_EmailInvoices_TeamMember_ItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        HiddenField JobId = (HiddenField)e.Item.NamingContainer.Parent.Parent.FindControl("HF_JobId");
        Label SalesInvoiceId = (Label)e.Item.NamingContainer.Parent.Parent.FindControl("Lab_SalesInvoiceId");
        HiddenField Lab_SalesInvoiceId_Nest = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HF_SalesInvoiceId_Nest");
        HiddenField Lab_JobId_Nest = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HF_JobId_Nest");
        Lab_SalesInvoiceId_Nest.Value = SalesInvoiceId.Text;
        Lab_JobId_Nest.Value = JobId.Value;
    }
}
```